# multiple model object inheritance in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

In django, I have three models:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    pass

class ChildA(Base):
    pass

class ChildB(Base):
    pass
```

I'm using MySQL, so after `syncdb`, I have three table:

`tb_base`, `tb_childa` and `tb_childb`, which the primary of both `tb_childa` and `tb_childb` are also foreign key of the primary key of `tb_base`.

Structurally speaking, I can have objects of Model `Base`, `ChildA` and `ChildB` having the 
 same id.

For example, now I execute:

```
childa = ChildA.objects.create()
print(childa.pk) # printed: 1
```

The above code added one row in `tb_base` and `tb_childa`, both with primary key `id` to be
1.

Now I want to create a `ChildB` instance, but it shares the base object of `childa`.

For example:

```
# this doesn't work, but shows what I want to do. 
childb = ChildB.objects.create(base=Base.objects.get(pk=1))
```

---

My final purpose is to use `ChildA` and `ChildB` Models in different cases, but if it's base part fields updated, they can share it.

Also, I want to consider the behavior when the objects be deleted.

Comment: in think when your inheriting no need to create a childb object since onece primary key of base 1 is created both the class have same 1 why to create a new one

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much sense in this, but you can do:

```
childb = ChildB.objects.create(base_ptr_id=1))
```

You might consider to define another class which holds shared data between ChildA and ChildB.

```
from django.db import models


class SharedData(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField("Data", max_length=50)


class Base(models.Model):
    shared_data = models.ForeignKey(SharedData)


class ChildA(Base):
    pass


class ChildB(Base):
    pass
```

Comment: In your solution, the problem still there.

Comment: Which problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
child_b = Base.objects.get(pk=1)
child_b.__class__= ChildB
child_b.save()
```